# Why is dictionary lookup slower than recursive search?

Tags: c#, recursion, dictionary

I was trying to optimize a search for a node in a `TreeNodeCollection`. The original method uses recursive approach:

```
public UGTreeNode FindNode(BaseId nodeId, TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    foreach (UGTreeNode n in nodes)
    {
        if (n.node_info.Description.base_id.Id == nodeId.Id &&
            n.node_info.Description.base_id.RootId == nodeId.RootId &&
            n.node_info.Description.base_id.SubId == nodeId.SubId)
            return n;
        UGTreeNode n1 = FindNode(nodeId, n.Nodes);
        if (n1 != null)
            return n1;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I tried storing all nodes in a `Dictionary` and use `Dictionary.TryGetValue` to search for a node:

```
public UGTreeNode FindNode(BaseId nodeId, TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    UGTreeNode res;
    _nodesCache.TryGetValue(nodeId.Id, out res);
    return res;
}
```

But it turns out that the second approach is way slower than the first (appoximately 10 times slower). What are the possible reasons for this?

Comment: This is interesting. In general, if a collection contains more than ~10-20 items, a hashed search should always be faster than a loop. Are you sure that _nodesCache contains the same items as your tree? Does the two methods produce the same result?

Comment: how many items do you have in your collection? (How) did you implement Equals and GetHashCode? (Or are these library types I don't know?)

Comment: @Dan, yes, this two methods produce the same results. When a node is added to the tree it is also added to `_nodesCache`.

Comment: To extend Dans answer: A HybridDictiorary transforms autmatic to a Hashtable if it contains enough items. Also i think (but im not sure) TryGetValue can make it slower. Maybe it would be faster to put a trycatchblock (and check for null) arround var temp = _nodesCache[nodeId.Id];

Comment: @DmitryErokhin: Just out of curiosity, in the recursive approach, you are comparing `Id`, `RootId` and `SubId`, while in the dictionary approach, you're only comparing `Id`. What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: @Dan, just for the sake of simplicity. I used a struct of `Id`, `SubId` and `RootId` as a key, but decided to leave only `Id` for the question, to be sure that it is not the struct constructor what slows the search. The program works with Exchange databases and `SubId` and `RootId`  are significant only for Exchange 2013 files.

Answer (score 1):

The recursion may be faster when you always search for one of the first items in the tree. It also depends on the `Equals` implementation of the `BaseId` or the comparer you use in the dictionary. In the recursive method, you have reference comparison. The dictionary uses the `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.

How did you measure the performance?

Comment: By wrapping the method in a `try-finally` block, adding a stopwatch,`calling `Start` at the beginning of the method and `Stop` at the `finally` block. I also added a call counter and output `Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds` when it reached 1000 calls.

Comment: How many items are in the collection? Which items are accessed? It may be too inaccurate to measure over a single item access. I would measure the time to access all items in the collection.